Spatially Varying Energy Gap in a Superconductor
The energy of a quasiparticle in a superconductor is given by
$$E_k=\sqrt{\Delta_k^2 + \epsilon_k^2} \approx \sqrt{\Delta^2 + \epsilon_k^2}$$
Where $\epsilon$ is the kinetic-energy of the would-be plane electron, and $\Delta$ is the gap energy. Suppose that the gap-energy spatially varies, $\Delta=\Delta(x).$ Now my question is: if a quasiparticle moves between regions with a different gap-energy, does the changing $\Delta$ induce some effective force?
Thinking classically, if the total energy of the quasiparticle remains constant, but the $\Delta$ changes, and $\Delta$ is some "effective potential energy," then we would expect the kinetic energy portion of the total energy to change too. So there might be some force related to the change in $\Delta,$ i.e. $F=-\frac{d \Delta}{dx}.$
